Appropriate step resolution and step frequency for given stepper motor speed
The stepper motor I want to drive will work at many different velocities in a robotic arm. The rotational velocity of a stepper motor depends on both the step frequency and the step resolution. But those are two variables and one equation. Is there any official recommendation on how big the step resolution or step frequency should be given rotational velocity?
I was thinking about just dividing the range of speeds by the amount of step resolutions and assigning the smaller step sizes to lower velocities. Would that be good?

I assume you're talking about microstepping, given that you have variable step resolution. The answer partly depends on how "agile" your motor controller is, in terms of being able to change the step resolution on the fly.
Microstepping implies that the driver is using PWM to modulate the current in the motor coils, and that PWM is happening at some (usually fixed) frequency. In general, it doesn't make sense to allow the step frequency to get anywhere close (within an order of magnitude) of the PWM frequency — the coil current doesn't have time to stabilize before the next step occurs. So that puts an upper limit on your step frequency.

The motor will have a torque-speed curve that tells you how close you are to missing steps for a given situation. That may vary somewhat with the microstepping resolution, but probably not a lot (could be wrong on that). Generally you want a higher voltage driving a lower voltage motor when you've got a chopper controller since that helps mitigate the inductance of the coils.
On something like a robot arm you have the kinematics of the robot arm to consider too. The torque required to accelerate a given mass being held by an end effector with an extended arm is going to be higher than the torque required if the arm is not extended.
